# Div mouseover, disappears

Tags: jquery, html, mouseover

Does this script to get a div that drop down on mouseover, but it disappears div as drop down when I stand with the mouse over it? to serve as a shopping card.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.cart_holder").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
        $("div.cart_container").css('visibility','visible');
    });
    $("div.cart_holder").mouseout(function() {
        $(this).css('cursor', 'default');
        $("div.cart_container").css('visibility','hidden');
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="cart">
    <div class="cart_holder">
        <span class="price">1 735 kr</span>
        <a class="icon_cart" href="#"></a>
        <a class="toggle_cart" href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="cart_container" style="visibility:hidden">
        <div class="cart_pro_box">
            <div class="img_holder">
                <img class="img" src="img/street_old_fashion_30594.jpg" alt="Street old Fashion" title="Street old Fashion" />
            </div>
            <div class="rub">
                <span class="title">Street old Fashion 6-Pack</span><br />
                <span class="name_artist">av Jan Johansson</span>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
                <span class="price_pay">1 439 kr</span><br />
                <span class="price_old">1 800 kr</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what was it that changed, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might help u.
I have changed the structure a little bit.also changed the `visibility` property.. :)

Using `Jquery`

http://jsfiddle.net/RKrsu/

Using `CSS`

http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/RKrsu/2/

Thanx pete :)

Comment: you are rite Pete.But the question is being tagged in jQuery rit..?? ;)

Comment: Hello,

Yes, it works fine on the link you posted, but not when I put it on the side (s10.se/agv).

Comment: sorry,what is (s10.se/agv)..??

Comment: s10.se/avg thats my site.

Comment: you need to remove the inline style visibility:hidden from the div `cart_container` and this div should be inside the `cart_holder` div

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?
[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Vbyec/NHqD9/)
**JS:**

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".cart_holder").mouseover(function () {
           $(".cart_container").show();
       });
       $(".cart_holder").mouseout(function () {
           $(".cart_container").hide();
       });
   });
```

**CSS:**

```
.cart_holder {cursor:pointer; }
```